# Why didn't Jack O'Neill retire?

Tags: stargate

Stargate SG-1 starts with O'Neill being pulled, reluctantly, out of retirement. At the time, he's one of very few people to have been through the Stargate, and his experience is direly needed.

As of Stargate Universe, SG-1 is scattered to the winds, the Stargate project is quite mature and filled with knowledgeable experienced people, and while O'Neill's knowledge and expertise is certainly helpful, it doesn't seem like there's the vital need for him that there once was.

So why did he take up a position in the military hierarchy instead of retiring again?

Comment: Because as he is a general, and a veteran of the SGC when the planet is about to be destroyed he can gate to the beta site and avoid dieing. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, before the season one there had been completely nothing military could offer Jack that he would have liked. So he retired to spend lonely nights on the roof with the telescope looking at the stars. And as for Stargate Universe we have completely another case. For eight years he had seen things the majority of people have never ever dreamed about; he made friends anobody could only wish to have and "Let's save this world once again" thing never gets old. Yes, the original SG-1 no longer exists, but from what we saw in the end of SGU season 1 Sam is under Jack's direct command (sort of) and Daniel is always around. So why  retire? He would just become a lonely old man with a telescope and hurting knees and a lake without fish while his friends and colleagues are busy saving the universe. And when as a general he has practically everything an older man (no offence, Jack!) could dream of, and just in case something happens to his friends he is the first to be informed (let's face it: everybody knows how many Earth's ships have been destroyed and how many of their captains are dead know) and that's much more better than to be retired and with comletely no information. (Although Sam/Jack shippers would tell you a completely another story, but right now we aren't talking about them)

Comment: Re: His lake without fish, correct me if I'm wrong but as the results of, I want to say, Stargate: Continuum, his lake does now have fish... Doesn't it?

Comment: Not quite sure about Continium, bit now it came to mind that they messed up with the timeline in "Mobius" and Jack mentioned that there was some fish now. But come on, our favourite general would be bored after a week or so. Through all the seasons his goal was to drag his team to the cabin and he succeed: first it was Teal'c, then the rest of the team and that was the fun. And fishing alone would drive him nuts very soon, and the only friends he has (as far as we know) to invite are involved in the Stargate Programm.

Comment: @Asmor - yes, at the end of Continuum, his lake did indeed appear to have fish.  And they even commented on that just before the credits rolled.

Comment: Actually, it was the 2-part episode "Moebius" (when SG1 goes back in time to steal a ZPM from RA) that resulted in his lake having fish: http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Moebius,_Part_2

Answer (score 13):

Before SG1, there was no reason for him to stick around. He has done his job and nuked Ra. Mission Accomplished. Nothing comparable to do in the future.

Whereas in SG series universe:

- He always has more stuff to do
- He has unique expertise which makes him effective, needed (even if not vital as the question notes) and, for that matter, leads to promotion.
- He feels responsible for the rest of his team/friends/etc... as any true leader, he can't abdicate that responsibility even if the alternative is unlimited fishing he so richly deserves and wants.

Comment: I'm sure making General didn't hurt anything either...

Comment: @earsonartphoto - possible but I'm unsure... he wasn't in SG1 to make General (and might have even had an issue with getting a desk job); and he didn't retire after being promoted.

Comment: Not just the General thing, but also the fact that he's THE man in charge of Earth's entire Stargate Project. Everything from the current Atlantis team on Earth to the Icarus project, everyone reported to him. I would think being in charge of the whole shebang would probably be a rather large incentive to stay right where he's at.

Comment: Especially good on point three. He was clearly shown in the series to be a firm believer in "we leave no man behind," and always had an almost paternal care for those he worked with.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it was in large part related to his sense of responsibility. He's in charge of Earth's Stargate project (and, I believe, almost all of Earth's off-planet operations), because he is, in effect, a war hero, for his service on SG-1.
What I often forget, though is that he *also* has that job because all he's done in SG-1, the reputation he's built and the contacts and allies he's made, to say nothing of his massive experience with SG-related missions, make him actually one of the absolute best choices *for* the job. His sense of responsibility just doesn't allow him to pass it off to someone who wouldn't be as qualified, thus risking Earth's security, as well as the safety of all the SG-teams.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer lies more in the psychological evolution of the character than in what he can offer.

Before the events of the film Jack has retired from the military chain of command due to the death of his only child with his own gun leading the character to a state of self blame and deep depression. Still we're shown in the movie that his military training and code of honor forces him to go back to active duty.

The rest of the show is an evolution of the character to finally forgive himself for the death of his son. This is explored several times in the show. Since that was the original reason for Jack to leave the military, once the character evolves to overcome it, there's no reason for him no to stay in the military (except for Sam of course, which is solved by him leaving SG Command). So it's not a question of what he has to offer (which is a lot) but I him don't wanting to retire at all. After all he was willing to go back only due to it sense of duty, which tell us the loyalty of the character to the military world.

Comment: I agree, this is how I've always seen it. He retired due to his son's death, and over the course of SG1 he was given a new lease on life. He saw all sorts of incredible things and accomplished so much, that I always believed his work in the Stargate program gave him a second lease on life after his son died and his wife moved on. As Jack said in 'Children of the Gods', " I'll never forgive myself. But sometimes I can forget... Sometimes." SG1 gave him a reason to move on and a purpose to live, to retire would just let him wallow in sorrow again. He wouldn't do that now.